# Boost bind to operator[]

Tags: c++, sorting, boost, matrix, bind

I'm trying to sort a two-dimensional array `vector<vector<int> > a(M,vector<int>(N))` row-wise with respect to its n-th column like this:

```
sort(a.begin(),a.end(),
  (bind(&vector<int>::operator[],_1,n) >
   bind(&vector<int>::operator[],_2,n)));
```

however my compiler tells me

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘bind(<unresolved overloaded function type>, const boost::lambda::placeholder1_type&, int)’
error: no matching function for call to ‘bind(<unresolved overloaded function type>, const boost::lambda::placeholder2_type&, int)’
```

how should I resolve the call?

PS.: tried an even simpler version of the preceding access to operator[]

```
  vector<int> a(10);
  (bind(&vector<int>::operator[],_1,_2))(a,2);
```

which is an adapted copy-cut-and-paste directly from Karlsson's book. Getting

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘bind(<unresolved overloaded function type>, const boost::lambda::placeholder1_type&, const boost::lambda::placeholder2_type&)’
```

also for that...

Comment: Maybe, you or somebody else gets `sort(a.begin(),a.end(),_1[n]>_2[n]);` to work using Boost.Lambda. I did not for some reason.

Answer (score 3):

With Boost.Phoenix you can use what @sellibitze mentions in the comments:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/phoenix.hpp>

namespace phx=boost::phoenix;

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix
    {
        {1, 2, 3, 4},
        {4, 3, 4, 1},
        {9, 1, 0, 2},
        {3, 1, 5, 1}
    };

    const auto N = 2;

    using phx::arg_names::_1;
    using phx::arg_names::_2;

    std::sort( matrix.begin(), matrix.end(), _1[N] > _2[N] );

    for(const auto& row: matrix)
    {
        for(const auto& elem: row)
            std::cout << elem << ' ';

        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`std::vector` has `const` and non-`const` versions of `operator[]`, and compiler can't deduce, which overloading should be used. You could do something like this:

```
template <class R, class T, class... Args>
auto const_mem_fn(R (T::* pm)(Args...) const)
    -> decltype(std::mem_fn(pm))
{
    return std::mem_fn(pm);
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix
    {
        {1, 2, 3, 4},
        {4, 3, 4, 1},
        {9, 1, 0, 2},
        {3, 1, 5, 1}
    };

    const auto N = 2;

    std::sort
    (
        matrix.begin(), matrix.end(),
        boost::bind(const_mem_fn(&std::vector<int>::operator[]), _1, N) >
        boost::bind(const_mem_fn(&std::vector<int>::operator[]), _2, N)
    );

    for(const auto& row: matrix)
    {
        for(const auto& elem: row)
            std::cout << elem << ' ';

        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Or, without `const_mem_fn`:

```
const int& (std::vector<int>::*op_sq_br)(std::size_t) const = &std::vector<int>::operator[];

std::sort
(
    matrix.begin(), matrix.end(),
    boost::bind(op_sq_br, _1, N) >
    boost::bind(op_sq_br, _2, N)
);
```

Output:

> 3 1 5 1
>   4 3 4 1
>   1 2 3 4
>   9 1 0 2

Comment: why do I need to do (const int& (std::vector<int>::*op_sq_br)(std::size_t) const)?

Comment: @Mark, As I already said, compiler can't deduce, which overloading should be used: `const` version or non-`const`. In this line we create a pointer, that points to `const` version.

Comment: sorry, wasn't finished commenting. I like your 2nd solution, but now I'm having elementary c++ problems: I don't understand in which namspace the function op_sq_br resides. I (wrongly) read it to be  within std::vector<int>. But from your usage of bind, it seems this is not the case. Speaking differently why would (const int& (*op_sq_br)(std::size_t) const) == &std::vector<int>::operator[]; not be sufficient/correct for your way of using bind?

Comment: @Mark, you can't just write `(*op_sq_br)`, since `operator[]` is a class member function. [Look this](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/fnptr-vs-memfnptr-types.html) for best understanding.

Comment: @Mark, `&std::vector<int>::operator[]` refers to an overload set. If you pass this to a function template like bind which accepts almost anything, there is not enough information on how to resolve the ambiguity between the two overloads. But in soon's second solution, this ambiguity is resolved by the type of `op_sq_br`. `op_sq_br` can only refer to one of the two operators due to its type.

Answer (score 2):

As @soon said, `&std::vector<int>::operator[]` refers to an overload set. But you can't pass such a thing to a function template and expect it to deduce its type because its type depends on which overload you meant. So, somewhere you would have to disambiguate it manually.

If you can make use of C++11 features, you should be writing

```
std::sort(a.begin(),a.end(),
    [=](vector<int> const& a, vector<int> const& b) {
        return a[n] > b[n];
    } );
```

to get rid of the overloading issue. Here, the const overload would be used simply because a and b refer to const vectors.

If you want it to be C++98 compatible another alternative is to write your own functor for applying the subscript operator:

```
template<class ResultType>
struct apply_subscript {
    typedef ResultType result_type;
    template<class T, class U>
    ResultType operator()(T const& x, U const& y) const { return x[y]; }
    template<class T, class U>
    ResultType operator()(T      & x, U const& y) const { return x[y]; }
};

:::

using namespace boost;
sort(mat.begin(),mat.end(),
    bind(apply_subscript<int>(),_1,n) >
    bind(apply_subscript<int>(),_2,n)
);
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add a C++11 solution in here, since you don't really gain anything by using Boost here.

A simple lambda solution would work best: `std::sort( a.begin(), a.end(), [n]( std::vector< int > first, std::vector< int > second ){ return first[n] < second[n]; } );`

Using `bind` largely increases the complexity of the problem: `std::sort( a.begin(), a.end(), std::bind( std::less< int >(), std::bind( static_cast< const int&( std::vector< int >::* )( size_t ) const >( &std::vector< int >::operator[] ), std::placeholders::_1, n ), std::bind( static_cast< const int&( std::vector< int >::* )( size_t ) const >( &std::vector< int >::operator[] ), std::placeholders::_1, n ) );`

I don't see any reason to be, but if you're really attached to `bind` over lambdas you can minimize the nastiness of the `static_cast` by doing this:

```
auto columnChooser = std::bind( static_cast< const int&( std::vector< int >::* )( size_t ) const >( &std::vector< int >::operator[] ), std::placeholders::_1, n );
std::sort( a.begin(), a.end(), std::bind( std::less< int >(), columnChooser, columnChooser );
```